# Webpack and Babel configuration problem on Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

i'm trying to build new project, i wanted it to have webpack and babel, app works, refreshes on webpage but i'm having issue with what i get in Chrome Dev Tools. I tried with adding babel-plugin-add-module-exports. I'd like to see the same in Sources as i see in my code. What i'm missing?

For example my file Contact.js looks:

```
 
const Contact = () => {
    return (
       <div>
          <h1>Contact US</h1>
          <p>Contact US page body content</p>
       </div>
    );
}
 
export default Contact;
```

but on devtools in Sources i'm getting:

```
/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {
/* harmony export */   "default": () => __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__
/* harmony export */ });
/* harmony import */ var react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! react */ "./node_modules/react/index.js");


var Contact = function Contact() {
  return /*#__PURE__*/react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createElement("div", null, /*#__PURE__*/react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createElement("h1", null, "Contact US"), /*#__PURE__*/react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createElement("p", null, "Contact US page body content"));
};

/* harmony default export */ const __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ = (Contact);
```

webpack.config.js

```
import HtmlWebPackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "newstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --mode development --env development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^1.0.4",
    "html-loader": "^1.3.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0-alpha.6",
    "webpack": "^5.1.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

.babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env", 
      "@babel/preset-react"],
      
    "plugins": [
      [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        {
          "loose": true
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```

Comment: That's what webpack does, it bundles all your modules together and stuff. If you want to debug the script, it's recommended that you have webpack build sourcemaps along with it so it can essentially "map" the compiled code back to your original JS files.

Answer (score 0):

As Matti mentioned you will need sourcemaps and details can be found on the webpack official site at https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/

You webpack will look like note the addition of devtool: 'source-map'

```
import HtmlWebPackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
devtool: 'source-map',
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```